# Paypal shop link sequrity

Tags: paypal

For receiving money from clients here

```
https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart
```

can be copy a code where is an onApprove function

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            // Full available details
    console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
    // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
    //const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
    //element.innerHTML = '';
    //element.innerHTML = '<h3>{{__("Thank you for your payment!")}}</h3>';
    // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('http://www.myservices.com/oneserviceBought?id=2323');//for example
});
```

How to rise security, that somebody (cyber attacker) cannot steal the service - instead of paying throw PP, copy the url http://www.myservices.com/oneserviceBought?id=2323 on his/her browser?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to secure such information is for the transaction to be created and captured from the server, and for only the server to eventually return or provide the redirect (or other credentials) once a capture is verified as successful.

There are details within [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) that explain how to program a server integration. Read that information, including the code demo pattern it links to.